# Getting a canvasjs graph to fit in a collapsed table row in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a canvasjs graph and want it to fit in a responsive table in Bootstrap.

I have created a large table in Bootstrap/HTML5 with one row defined as follows:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="100%" class="hiddenRow">
                            <div class="collapse" id="cellOneExp"> 
                                <div id="chartContainer1"></div>
                            </div> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

chartContainer1 refers to a dynamic graph created using canvasjs and has the following code:

window.onload = function () {

```
    var dps = []; // dataPoints

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",{
        zoomEnabled: true,
        title :{
            text: "Cell 1 Temperature (\xB0C)"
        },
        axisX: {
            title:"Time (seconds)",

        },
        axisY:{
            title: "Temperature (\xB0C)",
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: dps 
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 100;
    var dataLength = 5000; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function (count) {
        count = count || 1;
        // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
            xVal++;
        };
        if (dps.length > dataLength)
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }
        chart.render();     
        if (yVal>"100") {
            $('#alertHigh').slideDown(); //callback function will go in the brackets to slide the alert back up
            $('#alertLow').slideUp();
        } else if (yVal<"-100") {
            $('#alertLow').slideDown();
            $('#alertHigh').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#alertLow').slideUp();
            $('#alertHigh').slideUp();
        };
        //print stuff
        document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML=yVal + "&deg;C";



    };

    // generates first set of dataPoints
    updateChart(dataLength); 

    // update chart after specified time. 
    setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); }
```

The table has a button in it which has the id cellOneExp, so when that button is pressed the table should expand to show the graph.

If  is replaced with anything else (for example a p tag) the table expands appropriately. However with the graph present the table does not expand correctly. Instead the graph overlays the rest of the table elements and I cannot figure out how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/mg61tc37/

If not, can you please create a jsfiddle so that I can understand the issue properly.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks a lot!